# Angular5 - build Table with *ngFor

Tags: html-table, angular5, ngfor

I want to build a Table from a JSON

```js
this.adjacencyData = [{
  'x1': [{'x1': '0', 'x2': '1'}],
  'x2': [{'x1': '1', 'x2': '0'}]
}];
```

for the tableHead I do:

```js
for (let prop in this.adjacencyData) {      
  this.adjacencyDataKeys = Object.keys(this.adjacencyData[prop]);
}
```

and in the template:

```html
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th *ngFor="let key of adjacencyDataKeys">{{ key }}</th>      
  </tr>
</thead>
```

this works fine..

but how would I create the TableBody? I am trying out everything I find on the web.. but still I have no clue :/

I tried to do:

```js
for ( let _i = 0; _i < this.adjacencyDataKeys.length; _i++ ) {
  this.adjacencyDataVals = Object.values(this.adjacencyData[0][this.adjacencyDataKeys[_i]][0]);
}
```

and in the Template:

```html
<tbody>
   <tr *ngFor="let val of adjacencyDataVals"><td>{{val}}</td></tr>   
</tbody>
```

I get as output:

```html
<tbody _ngcontent-c8="">
 <tr _ngcontent-c8="" class="ng-star-inserted">
  <td _ngcontent-c8="">1</td>
 </tr>
 <tr _ngcontent-c8="" class="ng-star-inserted">
  <td _ngcontent-c8="">0</td>
 </tr>   
</tbody>
```

Can someone explain to me how this could be solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use another iterator inside this iterator

```
`<tbody>
   <tr *ngFor="let vals of adjacencyDataVals">
         <td *ngFor="let val of vals">{{ val }}</td> 
    </tr>   
</tbody>
```

`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the advice.. now it seems I got a step further.. but now I get a errorMessage `Cannot find a differ supporting object '1' of type 'string'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.`

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who has the same problem.. the final solution was this one:

1) define a array

```
adjacencyDataVals = [];
```

2) push only the values to this array

```
for ( let _i = 0; _i < this.adjacencyDataKeys.length; _i++ ) {     
  this.adjacencyDataVals.push(Object.values(this.adjacencyData[0][this.adjacencyDataKeys[_i]][0]));        
}
```

3) then do like `Karthikeyan M V` wrote:

```
<tbody>
 <tr *ngFor="let vals of adjacencyDataVals">
   <td *ngFor="let val of vals">{{ val }}</td> 
 </tr>
</tbody>
```

Big thanks to `Karthikeyan M V` ;)